# How can I store a Json responce in database in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby

How can I store the json response which I am getting form api into my database.
Here is what I want to do 
the responce from API:

```
[
  {
    "tag_id": "1",
    "tag_name": "FCC",
    "group_id": "15",
    "object_type_id": "0"
  },
  {
    "tag_id": "2",
    "tag_name": "SWA Buyers",
    "group_id": "15",
    "object_type_id": "0"
  },
  {
    "tag_id": "3",
    "tag_name": "SWA Nonbuyers",
    "group_id": "15",
    "object_type_id": "0"
  }
]
```

Now I want to store all the info in my table

Comment: If you're not looking to search using that data, check [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#class-ActiveRecord::Base-label-Saving+arrays-2C+hashes-2C+and+other+non-mappable+objects+in+text+columns). If you do need to search on the data, look at [PostgreSQL's `jsonb` and `hstore` support](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_postgresql.html#json)

Comment: Please specify what database you are using.

Comment: @c0de222 I am using mysql database

Answer (score 1):

You have plenty of options here.

1. Store this JSON as a string (in a text column). This obviously won't let you do any queries against the data. You can only read it as a whole.
2. Parse the response and create individual Tag records in your database.
3. If your database supports it (postgresql, for example), store it in special json column. This is a middle of the previous two options: you get some querying capabilities and ease of saving.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as:

- You add a column to table which you want save that data example "info" column to students table which is text type
- In Student model, you add this line:

  ```
  serialize :info, Hash
  ```